# mongodb embeded document: large document with more embeded or small document with less embeded

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

Here is an example to my case:

There are 3 factory A, B and C.

Each of them produces same 30 products: P1, P2,...P3

there are two possible structure of the document:

```
{
id: 1,
base: 'A',
date: '01/01/2014',
products:
   [
   {name:'P1', quantity:20, weight:4},
   {name:'P2', quantity:19, weight:5},
   ...
   {name:'P30', quantity:25, weight:6}
   ]
}
```

or

```
{
id: 1,
product: 'P1',
date: '01/01/2014',
bases:
   [
   {name:'A', quantity:20, weight:4},
   {name:'B', quantity:19, weight:5},
   {name:'C', quantity:25, weight:6}
   ]
}
```

The difference is the number of total documents and the number of embedded documents.

Actually, for the convenience of the use of the document, it doesn't make too much difference for me.

I want to ask what are the pros and cons between these two structures in MongoDB and will it make a significant difference in performance.

For each day, there will be:

1. three documents, each with 30 embedded documents as the first condition **OR**
2. thirty documents, each with 3 embedded documents as the second condition

Usually, the task will be just:

1. calc the sum of quantity for each product for a time period
2. calc the sum of produced quantity for each base for a time period
3. check the production detail of a base for the given day (the output is similar
   to the first condition structure)
4. check the production detail of a
   product for the given day (the output is similar to the second
   condition structure)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of difference in numbers are we talking about? What queries do you expect to throw at your database?

Comment: @Sammaye I have updated the content, hope you can get what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> three documents, each with 30 embedded documents as the first condition OR

The only difference I can see here is that as embedded documents (the first schema) you might suffer fragmentation on the default setting of MongoDBs document padding, with the powerof2sizes enabled http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes , of course if you are using v2.6+ then this setting is already on and you will see no difference.

> calc the sum of quantity for each product for a time period

This is favoured by the second schema, however:

> calc the sum of produced quantity for each base for a time period
>
> check the production detail of a base for the given day (the output is similar to the first condition structure)
>
> check the production detail of a product for the given day (the output is similar to the second condition structure

Is actually favoured by the first, querying by base.

So currently I would say go with first since it will be easier to fill your queries.

Comment: Thanks so much about your detailed answer. At first my focus is solely on which structure is superior, but after think about the ease of query as you stated, it makes thing more clear.

Comment: @Survi indeed, one of the core design principles in MongoDB is "Design around your queries", so your schema will always be reliant on your queries in MongoDB